# Black screen ASUS Transformer TF301, what can I do to recover?

Tags: asus-eee-pad-transformer

My Transformer TF301 is stuck at a black screen, well sort of a backlit black screen.

I have tried Volume Down-Power (for 10, 20, and 30 seconds) no joy.  VolumeUp-Power, no joy.

Finally found something thin enough (staple in the end) to push the hardware reset button.

No joy.

Holding power is not shutting it off either.

My son (six years old) is the only real user, and I cannot imagine he installed/rooted it. I see no visual sign that he damaged it.  It is in a case as well, which should mitigate any physical damage he might cause.

If I hold power button it goes black, but any other press and you get a backlit black screen.  Nothing seems to budge it.

What are my options to recover?

Comment: Is there any visible damage to the tablet (from a drop or liquid spill, for example?)

Comment: None.  Looks perfect.  Do not think he dropped it.  It is in a case, and he watches in carpeted rooms.

Comment: Are you able to boot it in Recovery mode by holding Vol Down and Power buttons together for 10-15 seconds?

Comment: @Chahk As I addressed in the question itself, no.

Comment: Try doing the Vol Down+Power combination again, and then while it's in that state connect it to a PC via USB cable.  Does the PC recognize an external device (and try to download drivers?)  Basically trying to see if only the screen is somehow damaged.

Comment: @Chahk Since it never gets into ANY state with Vol Down + power, nothing else happens when it is connected.  I get an icon for the Transformer. but no file system to browse.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13706/discussion-between-chahk-and-geoffc)

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I took it to a computer store that fixes screens and was informed a soldered wire had come loose, was re-soldered and it continues to work fine to this day.  Was only $30 to fix!